# Why is the Blazor value not immediately being rendered after changing it?

Tags: c#, winforms, blazor, maui-blazor, blazorwebview

Using a [BlazorWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webview.maui.blazorwebview) control ([introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview)) inside a WinForms .NET 8 form, I do have this "Counter.razor" file being displayed:

```razor
<p><button @onclick="IncrementCount">Increment counter</button></p>
<p>@_counterValue</p>

@code
{
    private int _counterValue = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        _counterValue++;
    }
}
```

[image]

#### Correct behavior

The above code works perfectly:

1. The user clicks the button.
2. The variable is incremented.
3. The page displays the new variable value.

[image]

#### Incorrect behavior

Now I change the `IncrementCount()` method to this:

```cs
private void IncrementCount()
{
    SynchronizationContext.Current!.Post(
        delegate
        {
            _counterValue++;
        }, 
        null);
}
```

Now it misbehaves like this:

1. The user clicks the button.
2. The variable is incremented (now being "1").
3. The page still displays "0".
4. The user clicks the button again.
5. The variable is incremented again. (Now being "2").
6. The page displays "1".
7. and so on.

I.e. I always do have an off-by-one error.

#### Fixing it

To fix this, I do have to change my code to:

```cs
private void IncrementCount()
{
    SynchronizationContext.Current!.Post(
        delegate
        {
            _counterValue++;
            StateHasChanged();
        }, 
        null);
}
```

Now, after adding a call to `StateHasChanged()`, it behaves as intended:

1. The user clicks the button.
2. The variable is incremented.
3. The page displays the new variable value.

#### Context

The above usage of `SynchronizationContext` is a minimal example of a larger application where I have to dispatch calls through this mechanism (primarily because [I have to call other WinForms dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/threading-model#reentrancy)).

I do want to understand why the call to "StateHasChanged" is required as I want to avoid it.

In my real application (not the above minimal example) this would force to much re-rendering to be suitable for the application.

#### My question

Could someone please explain to me why the behavior is different whether I change the variable directly vs. changing it through `SynchronizationContext`?

Is there a change to make this working without the extra call to `StateHasChanged()`?

---

### Update 1

In my real world application I'm doing roughly these steps:

1. User clicks a Blazor button.
2. A WinForms form is shown.
3. After closing the form, I have to update some values in Blazor.

So this is the reason I am doing my code inside a `SynchronizationContext.Current!.Post()` call, as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/threading-model#reentrancy).

I've also tried to place my code into a queue and process this queue in an [`Application.Idle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.idle) event handler of my WinForms app, but this behaves just the same (the off-by-one error).

Comment: `_counterValue` is the captured variable in its current state. If you increment it beforehand, then do, e.g., `_counterValue++; SynchronizationContext.Current?.Post((state) => _counterValue += 0, null);`, you should get the same result. Otherwise the first call may seem to have no effect because the variable's value is seen as when captured

Comment: Thanks, @Jimi. I've updated my question with some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IncrementCounter` is posted to the *Synchronization Context* by the Renderer's UI Event process.  It's  passed as `callback` inside the `ComponentBase` UI handler.

```cs
Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
{
    var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
    var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
        task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

    // After each event, we synchronously re-render (unless !ShouldRender())
    // This just saves the developer the trouble of putting "StateHasChanged();"
    // at the end of every event callback.
    StateHasChanged();

    return shouldAwaitTask ?
        CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
        Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The full code can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/63c8031b6a6af5009b3c5bb4291fcc4c32b06b10/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs#L322

So what you're doing is posting this

```cs
{
    _counterValue++;
}
```

as a block of code into the *Synchronization Context* queue behind `IncrementCounter`.  `IncrementCounter` does all the rendering before your code is executed and mutates the `_counterValue`.

When it's changed directly the mutation takes place before `StateHasChanged` is called in the UI handler.

Question: Why do you want to post code directly to the *Synchronization Context*?

`ComponentBase` has the inbuilt function `InvokeAsync` to call any code that must be executed on the *Synchronization Context*   see - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/63c8031b6a6af5009b3c5bb4291fcc4c32b06b10/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs#L178

Note [personal]:

I now always change:

```cs
private void IncrementCount()
{ }
```

To this:

```cs
private Task IncrementCount()
{ 
    //work
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

It prevents Visual Studio automatically doing this when you type `await`:

```cs
private async void IncrementCount()
{ }
```

### Update:

Based on your update you need to call `StateHasChanged` in the posted [anonymous] method.

Note that you can disable all automatic calls to `StateHasChanged` in a component like this:

```cs
@page "/counter"
@implements IHandleEvent

@code {
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        return callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
    }
}
```

You then only call `StateHasChanged` when you need to.

Comment: What, you mean you routinely wrote "async void" before and weren't able to prevent yourself doing it?! :D

Comment: I don't understand why you want to change it to Task. It adds a lot of overhead if you never need it to be `async`. You can simply change it to `Task` manually if it ever becomes `async` later.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MrCakaShaunCurtis. I've updated my question with some more details.

Comment: @flackoverstow - I may have senior moments, but not that senior! If you type await in a method in Visual Studio it will add async to the method automatically. You may not notice. There are many, many questions on here where that has probably happened.

Comment: @LukeVo -  there isn't a *lot of overhead* because the `Task.Completed` returns a cached singleton.  I will quote from a Stephen Toub in depth article *How Async/Await Really Works in C#* -  *Having to allocate an additional object just to return such data is unfortunate (note it was the case with APM as well). For non-generic Task-returning methods, the method can just return a singleton already-completed task, and in fact one such singleton is provided by Task in the form of Task.CompletedTask.*

Comment: @LukeVo - the code that calls `IncrementCount` is `var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);`